# Determine where app was started from e.g. Home Screen, App Drawer, or Play Store

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

Is there a way to determine whether an Android app (main activity) was started by tapping its icon on the Home Screen, or from other places (such as the App Drawer, or even the Open button in the Google Play Store app)?

I need do do this in Java code, preferably in a method such as OnCreate.

Comment: The manifest does declare the intent-filter for a reason, but I think that is only for the launcher. You could try `getIntent()` in your main activity, and debug to see what data is available

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your suggestion. I tried `getIntent()` and `toUri()` to output the intent data and extras. Unfortunately there is no difference between running from the Home Screen and App Drawer, I get the same data (except for the `sourceBounds`, which aren't useful for my purpose).

Comment: I want to say that since the app drawer is part of the launcher that there shouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For android apps, once it's started, it always run until manually closed. You can press the history button to see whether the app that you are interested is there. If it is, it means that it's running in the background.

I don't think there's a way to tell whether the app is running from Home Screen ... etc.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, which was "how can you tell where the app was **started from**"